# Passing dynamic string resource to "Toast"

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a dynamic string to "Toast" .

I made a customized function :

```
  private void makeToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and then I am able to use this function to pass Toast messages like :

```
 makeToast("You must enter the PIN code for authentication.");
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to pass a dynamic string to it .
So I declared it in strings.xml like :

```
<string name="must_pin">You must enter the PIN code for authentication</string>
```

and tried to pass it like this :

```
makeToast(R.string.must_pin);
```

But it does not accept it and says that it cannot accept an "int" .... So how can I pass this to makeToast . What is the right format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you currently have it, you are only passing the reference ID. You need to use `getString()`

```
makeToast(getString(R.string.must_pin));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 R.string.must_pin
```

is an int, and your method expect a String.

You need to use getResources().getString(...)

```
makeToast(getResources().getString(R.string.must_pin));
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.must_pin` is an int variable. you should use `getResources().getString()` for accessing `String`s defined in `strings.xml` file.

```
makeToast(getResources().getString(R.string.must_pin));
```